# Facebook fanpage profile image through graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Does anyone know how to grab a fanpage's profile image through Graph API? I've tried using the Graph API explorer with `https://graph.facebook.com/FANPAGEidHERE/picture` and it's just loading indefinitely.

Comment: I tested your URL scheme with https://graph.facebook.com/dexter/picture and was correctly redirected to a CDN version.

I've seen similar results to this with user profiles as well, so it might be just a bug specific to the fanpage you're looking at.

Comment: propably, you have not permission to see picture for this fanpage ;)